# How to Wrap Text Around a Circle in Sprite Kit / Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a game with SpriteKit / Swift and I want to have an effect on the menu scene where I bend a string around a circle. The following picture is almost exactly what I am looking to accomplish.  http://www.heathrowe.com/tuts/typeonaapathimages/4.gif

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following code wraps the characters in a string around the top half of a circle by creating a label node for each character in the string, setting the position of the label to the appropriate location on the circle, and then rotating each label node so that it is tangent to the circle at that position.

```
class GameScene:SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view:SKView) {
        let radius = CGFloat(50.0)
        let circleCenter = CGPoint.zero

        let string = "Your Text Here"
        let count = string.lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let angleIncr = CGFloat.pi/(CGFloat(count)-1)
        var angle = CGFloat.pi
        // Loop over the characters in the string
        for (_, character) in string.characters.enumerated() {
            // Calculate the position of each character
            let x = cos(angle) * radius + circleCenter.x
            let y = sin(angle) * radius + circleCenter.y
            let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Arial")
            label.text = "\(character)"
            label.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
            // Determine how much to rotate each character
            label.zRotation = angle - CGFloat.pi / 2
            label.fontSize = 30
            addChild(label)
            angle -= angleIncr
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to easily change how much of the circle the text is covering?

Comment: Yes, you will need to change `angleIncr` and the initial value for `angle`.

Comment: Were you able to create the effect that you wanted to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Binary tree is a non linear data structure. It should and must have atleast two children to a single parent node.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).